# How to exclude a specific file in scp linux shell command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I am trying to execute the `scp` command in such a way that it can copy .csv files from source to sink, except a few specific CSV file.

For example in the source folder I am having four files:

```
file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, file4.csv
```

Out of those four files, I want to copy all files, except file4.csv, to the sink location.

When I was using the below scp command:

```
scp /tmp/source/*.csv /tmp/sink/
```

It would copy all the four CSV files to the sink location.

How can I achieve the same by using the `scp` command or through writing a shell script?

Comment: This question seems to be more about command line options to `scp` and how to use file globbing. Perhaps it would be better placed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) with the `--exclude` switch, e.g.

```
rsync /tmp/source/*.csv /tmp/sink/ --exclude file4.csv
```

Comment: in that case i need to install rsync on server. can we achieve the same by including scp in shell script?

Comment: rsync is commonly pre-installed on most *nix platforms these days - did you check to see whether it’s available on your server ?

Comment: rsync will work fine, but i am looking for the solution using scp. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Bash has an [extended globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) feature which allows for this. On many installations, you have to separately enable this feature with

```
shopt -e extglob
```

With that in place, you can

```
scp tmp/source/(!fnord*).csv /tmp/sink/
```

to copy all `*.csv` files except `fnord.csv`.

This is a shell feature; the shell will expand the glob to a list of matching files - `scp` will have no idea how that argument list was generated.

Comment: This will not work if the source is the foreign host.

Comment: @Wiimm have a look at my solution to compensate that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726073/azad), rsync is not an option for you. The solution presented by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56785086/8344060) works only if the source is on the client side. Here I present a solution using `ssh` and `tar`. `tar` does have the `--exclude` flag, which allows us to exclude patterns:

**from server to client:**

```
$ ssh user@server 'tar -cf - --exclude "file4.csv" /path/to/dir/*csv' \
  | tar -xf - --transform='s#.*/##' -C /path/to/destination
```

This essentially creates a tar-ball which is send over `/dev/stdout` which we pipe into a tar extract. To mimick `scp` we need to remove the full path using `--transform` (See [U&L](https://superuser.com/questions/71846/tar-extract-discarding-directory-structure)). Optionally you can add the destination directory.

**from client to server:**

We do essentially the same, but reverse the roles:

```
$ tar -cf - --exclude "file4.csv" /path/to/dir/*csv \
  | ssh user@server 'tar -xf - --transform="s#.*/##" -C /path/to/destination'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bash array to collect your larger set, then remove the items you don't want. For example:

```
files=( /tmp/src/*.csv )
for i in "${!files[@]}"; do
  [[ ${files[$i]} = *file4.csv ]] && unset files[$i]
done
scp "${files[@]}" host:/tmp/sink/
```

Note that our for loop steps through array indices rather than values, so that we'll have the right input for the `unset` command if we need it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the files are not at local system.

Comment: @azad : But in your original attempt, `scp /tmp/source/*.csv /tmp/sink/`, there was no notion of a foreign host! Both source and sink are local (/tmp) and I was wondering why you used `scp` then in the first place....

Comment: @azad, in your question, they ARE on the local filesystem. This answer matches the requirements specified in your question. Perhaps you can run this from the host that is the source. Otherwise, you need to let us know how the list of files should be gathered, as you appear to have posted an incomplete question.